# compute pitch, roll and yaw movement of an object in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation, simulator, robotics

I am currently working, with Matlab, on a 3D simulator whose aim is to move an object (currently it's just a  simple circle) in space (using plot3).

Although it's easy to compute a trajectory without any rotation of my object, I do not manage to rotate my object around its own axis. Indeed, I have computed the 3 well-known rotation matrix but it (of course) rotate  my object (represented by a set of points) around the axis of my figure (in the "world" system).

For example, the center of inertia of my object (currently the center of my circle) is I whose coordinates are (Xi,Yi,Zi). Thus, I suppose that I need to define an additional system for my object to be able to rotate my object about these 3 new axis composing such a system...

I would like something like:

`[X2,Y2,Z2]=Mat*[X1,Y1,Z1]` where `[X1,Y1,Z1]` is the coordinates of a point of my object before the rotation, `[X2,Y2,Z2]` the coordinates after the rotation and Mat the matrix I am looking for. Of course, the center of inertia must be unchanged whichever the rotation (yaw and/or pitch or/and roll)

However I have no idea about the way to compute such a matrix. The link below summarizes my wish.

[Drawing of my problem](http://hpics.li/0639a11)

Comment: You need to translate your object to the origin BEFORE rotation, and then translate it back to its original center AFTER rotation. This implies multiplying by two translation matrices on the right hand and on the left hand side of your rotation matices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I have to do : center my object (center of inertia I) in O --> rotate object --> translate object in I. However, how can I define the axis of rotation because even once I translated my object to the origin, the axis in the object system do not match the axis of my plot/figure.

Comment: then you'll have to keep track of the relative rotation of the object to the world coordinate system.

Comment: Could you be more accurate as I do not really see how to implement it. I thought it will be easier...

Comment: How can I keep track of the relative rotation of my two systems?

Comment: The link below seems to match my needs: http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~cs155/Lecture_07_6.pdf